# Не загружается файл

Tags: php, openserver

Всем привет. Подскажите, куда делся файл? Название файла в базу записывается. А файла нет. Работаю в OpenServer

```html
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])) {
    $fileName = '';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) { 
     $fileName .= mt_rand(1, 9);
    }
    $fileName .= '.png';
    $folder = '..\..\domains\shop\img\\';
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $folder .$fileName);
    $pathImg = 'img/'.$fileName;
    $query = "UPDATE products SET name = '$_POST[name]', type = '$_POST[type]', chassis = '$_POST[chassis]', electromotor = '$_POST[electromotor]', flight_time = '$_POST[flight_time]', price = '$_POST[price]', img = '$pathImg' WHERE id = $id";
   } else {
    $query = "UPDATE products SET name = '$_POST[name]', type = '$_POST[type]', chassis = '$_POST[chassis]', electromotor = '$_POST[electromotor]', flight_time = '$_POST[flight_time]', price = '$_POST[price]' WHERE id = $id";
   }
```

Comment: файл девается в папку ..\..\domains\shop\img\

Comment: нет его там, в том то и дело.

Comment: И всё-таки дико видеть в 2019 году пхп код который просто созывает всех хакеров, распахивая двери для инъекций

Comment: Я только учусь... Азы постигаю.

Comment: Это не азы, а кривизна. Никто не мещает постигать азы нормально, а не по учебникам прошлого века

Comment: Так может посоветуете хороший учебный материал? буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91957/discussion-between-roman-and-).

Comment: Это какая-то дич. не надо делать `$_POST[name]` Это не правильно и не продуктивно, как минимум там `Warning` о том, что не найдена константа `name`. Нужно заворачивать в `'` кавычки, то есть так: `$_POST['name']`, а вообще лучше использовать функцию `filter_input`. Да и у вас иньекция на ровном месте... Весь ваш код нужно стереть и написать нормально.

Comment: @And не будет там никакого Warning :) И Notice тоже не будет. и filter_input тут совсем не при чем. А вот инъекция будет - это верно

Comment: @Ипатьев, Да да, да. `Warning: Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name'`. Съел?

Comment: @Ипатьев, а теперь прожуй, вздохни и сново съешь: Такое поведение раньше вызывало ошибку уровня `E_NOTICE`, но теперь будет `E_WARNING`. В следующей основной версии `PHP` вместо ошибки будет выбрасываться исключение `Error`.

Comment: @And не вызывало и не будет :) Перед тем как отвечать, надо попробовать сначала. Запустить этот код. Ну и вообще уже должна выработаться привычка не спорить, когда я что-то сообщаю, а проверять свои выладки.

Comment: Если добавлять кавычки их придется экранировать.

Comment: @Ипатьев, с тобой никто и не спорил, ты несешь чушь, если не веришь зайди на оф сайт языка и посмотри открытыми глазами, а затем сам запусти   скрипт, если конечно у тебя отключены ошибки, то поздравляю, ты не увидешь ничего.

Comment: Роман, экранирование тут не поможет. Тут очень тут очень тонкий момент, который многие не понимают, в частности наш друг @And - парсинг переменных в строках РНР не так прост как кажется.

Comment: @Ипатьев, ты что несешь? Какие парсинги строк? Я тебе четко пояснил в чем проблема `$_POST[name]`. Включай мозги, хватит нести чушь.

Comment: @And чем брызгать слюнями, и тыкать в документацию, которую ты в глаза не видел, попробуй выплнить код из вопроса. После этого можешь прийти и вежливо попросить дядю ткнуть тебя носом в то место мануала, которое объясняет такое поведение.

Comment: @Ипатьев, [для трудно-доходяк, как ты](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/migration72.deprecated.php) - это 7.2+ пыхтачек, ниже нет смысла, там все еще хуже, чем тебе кажется, но лучше тебе перереститься. (а рыться в ранних версиях, не хочется искать для тебя особенно все есть в константах и супер-глобальных массивах про это) Для одаренных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример загрузчика файлов ( код не решение а исключительно пример )

```
    $TempSize = $_FILES['size'];

    if($TempSize > 1)
    { 

        //// Максимально допустимый размер загружаемого файла - 15Мб
                    $MaxFileSizeInBytes = 15242880;

                    $AllowFileExtension = array('jpg', 'png');



                $Fileformat = substr(strrchr($_FILES['name'],'.'), 1);
        // переименование файла
                $FileName =uniqid().'.' . $Fileformat;



        //// Полный путь до временного файла
                    $TempName = $_FILES['tmp_name'];


        //// Полный путь к новому файлу в папке сервера
                    $NewFilePatch = "upload/files/".$FileName;

                    if($_FILES['name']) 
                    {
        //// Проверка если расширение файла находится в массиве доступных
                    $FileExtension = pathinfo($_FILES['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                        if(!in_array($FileExtension, $AllowFileExtension)) 
                        {

            echo "ошибка   при загрузке файла '".$_FILES['name']."'.  неверный формат";                
                        echo"<br>";
                        }
                        else 
                        {

        //// Проверка размера файла
                            if(filesize($TempName) > $MaxFileSizeInBytes)
                            {
                            echo "Размер загружаемого файла превышает 15МБ";
                            echo"<br>";
                            }
                            else 
                            {

        //// Проверяем права доступа на папку

                               if(!is_writable("upload/files/")) 
                                           {
                               echo "Папка не имеет прав на запись";

                               }
                               else 
                               {

        //// Копируем содержимое временного файла $TempName и создание новых в папке сервера

                                      $CopyFile = copy($TempName,$NewFilePatch);

                                       if(!$CopyFile) 
                                       {
        //// сообщение без файла                                                                     

                                          echo "Ошибка загрузки";

                                        }
                                        else
                                        {

                                        echo " файл загружен ";

                                    }                                                                               
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
}
```